# Windows hostname not resolving to hosts file entry

Tags: domain-name-system, hosts

I have a Windows Server 2012 instance running software that requires that it map its hostname `OW5000` to its IP Address.

However, when pinging `OW5000`, it resolves to `::1`. In this instance, the software will not work. It requires the IP, let's say `10.10.10.21`.

I manually set the `hosts` file in order to override this loopback address:

```
# hosts
10.10.10.21  OW5000
```

Despite this, even with flushing the DNS afterwards, `OW5000` is still resolving to `::1`.

The computer is not on a domain so using DNS will not work as it needs to resolve `OW5000`, not a fully qualified Domain Name.

Is there a workaround to this?

---

#### UPDATE

Doing an `ipconfig /displaydns` displays the record twice:

```
ow5000
----------------------------------------
Record Name . . . . . : OW5000
Record Type . . . . . : 28
Time To Live  . . . . : 1200
Data Length . . . . . : 16
Section . . . . . . . : Question
AAAA Record . . . . . : ::1


ow5000
----------------------------------------
Record Name . . . . . : OW5000
Record Type . . . . . : 1
Time To Live  . . . . : 1200
Data Length . . . . . : 4
Section . . . . . . . : Question
A (Host) Record . . . : 10.10.10.21
```

Here's what gets interesting: the `Record Type` appearing on the loopback is `28`, which in looking it up, is IPv6! I have IPv6 disabled. But clearly it isn't and this is creating the problem.

So lost.

Comment: Are you sure there is no DNS service on the machine?  `nslookup OW5000 127.0.0.1` could clarify that.

Comment: @JuliePelletier I am getting `unknown can't find ow5000: server failed` and `unknown can't find ow5000: no response from server` when including `127.0.0.1` at the end.

Comment: `I have IPv6 disabled` - Do you mean that you unbound IPv6 from the NIC? If so, that isn't enough. - https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/929852

Answer (score 1):

Ping and Nslookup make different types of name resolution lookups.
See https://superuser.com/questions/495759/why-is-ping-unable-to-resolve-a-name-when-nslookup-works-fine

Does Nslookup work? Might also try putting the name in the LMHOSTS file instead of HOSTS.

You may also want to run this checklist [hosts file ignored, how to troubleshoot?](https://serverfault.com/questions/452268/hosts-file-ignored-how-to-troubleshoot)

Comment: Thanks. Went through that and came up with an update to my question!

Answer (score 0):

I [used this article to solve it](http://tweaks.com/windows/40099/how-to-properly-disable-ipv6/).

In essence, IPv6 was not actually really, truly disabled, so one has to set the registry setting contained in there, and then reboot.