# Windows not resolving local hostname to hosts file IP

Tags: windows, hostname, ip-address

I have a multi-homed Windows 10 and I want my application to open a Server Socket on a specific IP given by its *hostname*.

My machine hostname is `MY-PC` and it has a public IP `192.0.0.2/24` and a "direct" IP `192.2.2.2/24` (directly connected to another computer). Both are configured in the Windows Network Adapter page in the Control Panel.

No DNS is configured. My hosts file looks like:

```
127.0.0.1    localhost
192.2.2.2    MY-PC
192.2.2.1    DIRECT-PC
```

When I try to ping my hostname ([after fully disabling IPv6](https://tweaks.com/windows/40099/how-to-properly-disable-ipv6/)):

```
> ping MY-PC

Pinging MY-PC [192.0.0.2] with 32 bytes of data:
Reply from 192.0.0.2: time<1ms
...
```

A strange thing is that the same setup (hosts file/network adapter configuration) works as expected on another computer (but just one out of six).

How can I force listening on a specific IP from a hostname? (which is a global parameter from a configuration received by the program).

I have already checked [a related question](https://serverfault.com/questions/788800/windows-hostname-not-resolving-to-hosts-file-entry) but the answer is about fully disabling IPv6.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please read [this article](https://support.microsoft.com/en-au/help/172218/microsoft-tcp-ip-host-name-resolution-order), there you could find more about name resolution in Windows. Below answer to your question:

> Host name resolution generally uses the following sequence:
>
> 1. The client checks to see if the name queried is its own.
> 2. The client then searches a local Hosts file, a list of IP address and names stored on the local computer.
> 3. Domain Name System (DNS) servers are queried.
> 4. If the name is still not resolved, NetBIOS name resolution sequence is used as a backup. This order can be changed by configuring
>      the NetBIOS node type of the client.
>
> The Windows client will try each of these methods until it either successfully resolves the name or exhausts these methods.

Comment: Thanks. So it's clearly #1. So how can I tell which IP to use for my hostname? (looks like NetBIOS?)

Comment: @Matthieu How I can understand, it's impossible. But you could add to hosts file entry `192.2.2.2    MY-PC-DIRECT` and bind your application on this hostname.

Comment: Thanks again Alexander, that's what I'm doing right now but I wanted to make sure there was no other way than creating a second hostname just for that purpose. Ah, Windows, dear Windows...