# Is there any IETF / RFC standard defined for hosts file encoding?

Tags: windows, encoding, hosts-file, rfc

While going through the accepted answer for [hosts file ignored, how to troubleshoot?](https://serverfault.com/questions/452268/hosts-file-ignored-how-to-troubleshoot), I observed the statement "The hosts file should encoded in ANSI or UTF-8 without BOM". As I personally faced issues using an application due to hosts file in unicode format in a Windows machine, trying to find if there is any IETF / RFC standard defined for hosts file, specifying the supported list of encodings.

Could somebody here please help me. Thanks.

Comment: Host file content format and encoding is going to be entirely implementation-defined.

Comment: I don't think there was ever a formal grammar for it. Even Wikipedia's description of the format is an entire `[citation needed]` section.