# Why are my HOSTS file changes not taking effect in Windows 10?

Tags: windows-10, hosts

I made a change to my hosts file on my Windows 10 machine today, however after saving the changes in Notepad (running as admin) the changes do not appear to work.

For example I would expect this entry:

`127.0.0.1       google.com`

To stop a page from resolving to Google.com.

However, this doesn't appear to be happening and the web browser resolves to google.

Is there a cache setting I'm missing?

Thanks

Comment: Are you sure the page uses `google.com` and not `www.google.com`? Entries in hosts file are just for a single domain excluding subdomains.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [hosts file ignored, how to troubleshoot?](https://serverfault.com/questions/452268/hosts-file-ignored-how-to-troubleshoot)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to flush the DNS cache in Windows 10

Go to cmd and type

```
ipconfig /flushdns
ping google.com
```

now you shut return with 127.0.0.1 and restart your browser shut help to

Comment: Thanks.  Also cleared browser cache.